# Mac M2 makefile does not work, but command in gcc/clang does

Tags: c, makefile

I've been having this problem for some time now. I have a Macbook with an M2 chip and want to do some c++ programming again (it's been a time). I've used the simple program from this website https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ to make a simple C program and its makefile (want to start in c). The makefiles do not work (the first one already does not). The error thrown in the terminal is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_myPrintHelloMake", referenced from:
      _main in hellomake.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [hellomake] Error 1
```

The kicker is that running the commands from the makefile in the terminal work fine.

Also, I made another makefile myself (the way I used to), to try it:

```
hellofunc.o: hellofunc.c hellomake.h
    gcc -c hellofunc.c

hellomake.o: hellomake.c hellomake.h
    gcc -c hellomake.c

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o hellomake.h
    clang hellomake.o hellofunc.o -o hellomake
```

It gets the same error.

My question is, am I doing something wrong? I understand that there have been problems with Mac M1's in the past, but should I install something differently?

Btw, I'm not experienced here, so perhaps I've not explained myself well enough. Feel free to ask some more details.

Comment: Could you please tell us the output of `which gcc` and `which clang`?

Comment: Actually, please also post the output of `uname -m` if run directly from your terminal.

Comment: Yes. uname -m gives: arm64. gcc --version and clang --version give: Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: Why don't you post your two source files?   On an M1 mac with std tools, this works fine ( well awkward because the makefile order is odd, and I don't know why you would intermingle gcc and clang; or even use either when the defined $(CC) is always the right choice. )

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from your `make` program: you probably have an older version in your path compiled for the intel architecture.  When this `make` tool calls `clang` (or `gcc` which is an alias for the installed `clang` compiler), the compiler tries to generate object and/or executable files for the intel architecture, and the tools installed on your system cannot handle this.

Try and upgrade your `make` utility: use `which make` to identify which program is used and use the `file` command to check what architecture it is compiled for.  Rename this program and run `which make` again to see if another tool is available for the amd64 architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I also just update my make utility? 

I ran the first command you suggested. The output is:
/usr/bin/make.

I also ran make --version, which gave:

GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

Could you help me on how to fix it? I'm not sure what version of make I should use.

Comment: If this were the issue, I would expect the error to say `for architecture x86_64`, not `arm64`.

Comment: @T_h: your observations are consistent with my explanation: I am using the same laptop and my `make` also reports `This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0`, yet `file /usr/bin/make` reports `Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm4e]` which means it runs as a native executable, not inside the emulator.  Try `file /usr/bin/make` on your system.

Comment: On 'file /usr/bin/make' I get `/usr/bin/make (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/make (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e`. I don't know what I'm supposed to do with this part "Rename this program and run which make again to see if another tool is available for the amd64 architecture." of your answer.

Comment: @T_h: Your `make` program seems fine, how do you invoke it ?

Comment: I give the command `make hellomake`. I also tried the commands `make hellomake.o` and `make hellofunc.o` (with the second makefile, the one I made myself) and they work as planned. It only fails on compiling the final program. Is there another example I could try as a program, to see if it works?

Comment: @T_h: do you get the same problem using `clang` instead of `gcc` to produce the object files?  `gcc` is usually an alias for `clang` on macOS, but you might have installed a genuine gcc compiler targetting the x86 architecture.  Type `gcc --version` and change your makefile to use `clang` as the C compiler.

Comment: @chqrlie: yes, I get the same error. Both when I use clang and gcc in the entire makefile, I get the error. `gcc --version` returns: Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin